# AttributeError when calling instance method I defined

Tags: python

I coded this in python 3 and it is showing an attribute error.code is 
as following:

```
import datetime 

class MessageUser():
  User_Details = []
  Messages = []
  base_message = """Hi {name}! 
  Thank you for the purchase on {date}. 
  We hope you are exicted about using it. Just as a
  reminder the purcase total was ${total}.
  Have a great time!

  from Pritom_Mazhi
  """

  def add_user(self, name, amount, email=None):
    name = name[0].upper() + name[1:].lower() #Capitalizing the first letter of all names - formatted name
    amount = "%.2f" %(amount) #formatted amount 
    detail = {
      "name" : name,
      "amount" : amount,
    }
    today = datetime.date.today()
    date_text = '{tday.day}/{tday.month}/{tday.year}'.format(tday=today) #formatted date 
    detail["date"] = date_text
    if email is not None:
      detail["email"] = email
    self.User_Details.append(detail)

    def get_details(self):
      return self.User_Details

    def make_message(self):
      if len(self.User_Details) > 0:
        for detail in self.get_details():  #for detail in self.User_Details
          name = detail["name"]
          amount = detail["amount"]
          date = detail["date"]
          email = detail["email"]
          message = self.base_message
          formatted_message = message.format(
            name = name,
            total = amount,
            date = date,
            )
          self.Messages.append(formatted_message)  
          return self.Messages
      else:
          return []


obj = MessageUser()
obj.add_user("Pritom", 123.32, email='hello@teamcfe.com')
obj.add_user("jon Snow", 94.23)
obj.add_user("Sean", 93.23)
obj.add_user("Emilee", 193.23)
obj.add_user("Marie", 13.23)
obj.get_details()

obj.make_message()
```

when i run it i get this error:

```
File "Class_StringFormat.py", line 57, in <module>
    obj.get_details()
AttributeError: 'MessageUser' object has no attribute 'get_details'
```

i simply can't find what wrong i did there and so can't manage to fix it.

Comment: You might want to rephrase the title of your question. It should be an indication of what you are asking.

Comment: Btw: The error could be caused by the indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your indentation is reproduced correctly in the question, `get_details` is defined **inside** `add_user` and is not visible from outside.

You should unindent the definition of `get_details` and `make_message` to be on the same level as `add_user`:

```
def add_user(self, name, amount, email=None):
   # method body...

def get_details(self):
   return self.User_Details

def make_message(self):
   # method body
```

Comment: ok,thank you very much for the solution.after I make the indentations correctly- if i do
 print(obj.make_message())
in the last line ,it only shows the message for "pritom" only and not for the"jon snow,sean,emilee,marie" etc.
how can i fix that? 
i want the code work in a way that it would print all messages for all after it executes 
 print(obj.make_message())
this line only once.

Comment: @SamiulSalehin the problem is in make_message, where you have a return statement inside the for loop. It returns on the first iteration, and the rest of the loop is not executed. You need to return after the loop is finished.

Comment: @SamiulSalehin great! Consider marking the answer as accepted to show that your problem is resolved.

Comment: i'm new to ques and answering in stackoverflow.can you kindly tell me how to mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: @SamiulSalehin you should see a tick to the left from the answer, which you can click on to accept it